# How could I know if this function is strictly decreasing in m?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, mathematical-optimization

I have the following function:

```
((-2 b m - 2 w1 - 5 w2 + 3 m w2 + 7 w3 - 3 m w3 + Sqrt[
 4 b^2 m^2 + (-2 w1 + w2 - 3 m w2 + w3 + 3 m w3)^2 + 
  4 b m (2 w1 + (5 - 3 m) w2 + (-7 + 3 m) w3)])/(6 (-1 + m) (w2 - w3)))
```

Subject to the following parameters restrictions:

```
w2 > w3 && w1 > 2 w2 - w3 && 0 < m < 1 && w3 > b > 0
```

I am trying to show that the previous function is strictly decreasing in m, given the range of the parameters. I tried to derivate the function, but the result is a very long expression. All the plots I did of the function gave me a strictly decreasing function.

Does anyone have an idea of how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance,

Pau

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
expr = ((-2 b m - 2 w1 - 5 w2 + 3 m w2 + 7 w3 - 3 m w3 + 
     Sqrt[4 b^2 m^2 + (-2 w1 + w2 - 3 m w2 + w3 + 3 m w3)^2 + 
       4 b m (2 w1 + (5 - 3 m) w2 + (-7 + 3 m) w3)])/(6 (-1 + m) (w2 -
        w3)));
assumptions = w2 > w3 && w1 > 2 w2 - w3 && 0 < m < 1 && w3 > b > 0;
Reduce[
    D[expr, m] < 0 
    &&
    assumptions 
]
```

> w2 > 0 && 0 < w3 < w2 && w1 > 2 w2 - w3 && 0 < b < w3 && 0 < m < 1

```
Simplify[%, Assumptions -> assumptions]
```

> True

## Edit

I modified the answer after I noticed that `0 < m < 1` is part of your assumptions.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! However, I dont understand why the answer of your code is the assumptions of the parameters? Is not clear to me, why 0 < m < 1 should tell me that the function is not universally decreasing in m.

Comment: @pau1996 `Reduce` simply finds the a simpler way to state the same thing as you put in, so the assumptions you put in have to come back out again in some way. See, for example, `Reduce[x^2 + y^2 < 1 && x > 0, {x, y}]`. The fact that `0 < m < 1` is part of the output tells you that this is a requirement for `D[expr, m] < 0`. In other words, for other values of `m` is isn't true. Try adding `m > 1` to the assumptions: `Reduce` will return `False` then.

Comment: @pau1996 Oh, wait. I didn't catch that `0 < m < 1` is part of your assumptions. In that case, the fact that the assumptions come back tells you that `D[expr, m] < 0` is indeed true.

Comment: Ok, thank you! I did not make it sufficiently clear.

Comment: @pau1996 BTW, if you change the assumption to just `m > 0`, you'll notice that this is true for all positive values of `m` except `m == 1`.

Comment: Yes, that is true! Could you give me a little bit more insight on the meaning of the comand Simplify[%, Assumptions -> assumptions]? I would like to understand better what is the command doing

Comment: @pau1996 The line with `Simplify` takes the previous output (`%`) and, well, simplifies it using the assumptions given. Unlike `Reduce`, `Simplify` will not return the given assumptions but only reduce the target expression under the assumptions provided. You can also use `FullSimplify` for more complicated expressions. `Reduce`, on the other hand, is generally the most powerful. I recommend searching around in the documentation and on SE if you want to learn more. If you have a specific question about these functions, please post a new question.

Comment: Great! Thank you very much!